# SQLite Query runs way slower on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a query that runs perfectly fine on Gingerbread devices and Jellybean but runs a huge amount slower on Lollipop devices. I'm certain the query is correct and written well as it runs fine on the older devices.

```
Cursor c;
String query = QUERY STRING;

c = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{Integer.toString(a),Integer.toString(b)});

Log.e("SQL_QUERY_PROGRESS","1");

while(c.moveToNext()){
    Log.e("SQL_QUERY_PROGRESS","2");
    // Do stuff with data
}

c.close();
```

On the Gingerbread device there was only 0.008 of a second between the two log messages whereas on the Lollipop devices it was taking ~8 seconds which is incredibly slow.

What I can't fathom is that the Lollipop devices are newer and have more RAM, CPU power etc so surely logic dictates that the newer devices should run the query faster than the older devices.

Could there be a bug with the version of Java used on Lollipop or could the SQLite version cause this massive decrease in speed?

I've used `adb shell`
and navigated to the database file and ran the query using `sqlite3` on the Lollipop devices and it ran almost instantly so that makes me think it's more of a Java problem than SQLite problem.

I'm completely out of ideas of what could be causing the delay so any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated so I can investigate further!

Comment: Lollipop devices usually have `userdata` partition encrypted - that slows down many storage related operations including database access. Besides that a newer device does not always translate into faster storage. There are many factors at play. So unless you want to run your query on the same dataset on the same device just under different android versions and provide more info - your question is moot and off-topic

Comment: Are you running the query in the main thread or is it running in a separate thread (AsyncTask, Thread, IntentService...)?

Comment: @AlexP. I've ran it on a Nexus 5 and Galaxy S4 on Lollipop, on a Vodafone Smart II on Gingerbread and on a Galaxy S2 on Jellybean so surely those devices should be at least as quick if not quicker in theory and not a 1000 times slower!

Comment: @Sunil I've it running in the main thread. It's fine in the main thread on Gingerbread and Jellybean devices because it executes almost instantly but not for Lollipop

Comment: Could people please explain their opinion before down voting?

Comment: @PriestVallon - I did not down vote (I very rarely do)... but to get back to your question, is it only this specific query that is acting so? Because at roughly 8 seconds, I'm sure the app should trigger the dreaded App Not Responding (ANR). I'd suggest you use TraceView to figure out what's going on and try out the app in another device. Also how many rows are you returning?

Comment: `I've it running in the main thread.` So here is the problem. My advice is to run the query in an AsyncTask.

Comment: @DerGolem If the query runs fast enough it's fine to have it in the UI thread. And seeing as it runs fine on older devices I thought having it in the UI thread was fine.

Comment: Really, leave **the least possible** on the UI thread.

Comment: You're missing the point. I can easily move the query to a different thread but I'll still have to wait ~8 seconds on Lollipop devices which isn't satisfactory.

Comment: Did you test? does it still  take 8 secs while executing in a parallel thread?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved this.

1. First you need to figure out which queries are the problematic ones. I did this by replacing all `rawQuery()` calls with my own method. It will log the time between each query.

> ```
> private static Cursor runQuery(String query) {
>     System.out.println("QUERY: " + query);
>     Cursor tmpCursor = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);
>     System.out.println("TIME: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - Main.time));
>     Main.time = System.currentTimeMillis();
>     return tmpCursor;
> }
> ```

Check the time in other parts of your code that you suspect.
Now, you'll see in between which queries time is lost. It's actually the cursor logic, like `c.moveToFirst()` that are the expensive ones. Put a time check after those, too to verify.

2. When you've found the query, examine it and check what columns the query has to go through. In my case I had a join on a column that is in a table with a huge number of rows. That's the column you need for the next step:
3. Create an index for this column, like this:
   `CREATE INDEX idx_bibref ON responses(bibreference);`

You can run this in terminal for testing (sqlite3 ) or better yet put it in your `onUpgrade`method. 
That's it. Now all cursor methods run fast again, like on previous Android versions.

---

Old post:

I experience the same problem. I have it running in an Async task, so I can confirm that as PriestVallon said, this being run on the main UI thread, while not exactly efficient, is NOT the cause of the problem. 
It does only appear on Lollipop. Ran this on phones and emulators with 4.4. No issues. 
My investigation thus far has yielded that it's related to cursor logic and not the query itself. For example:

```
c.moveToFirst();
c.moveToNext();
c.getCount();
etc...
```

Usually when run after more complex queries with joins (but that I can't confirm 100% yet).

Maybe this can help.

(I apologize for putting this in an answer, opposed to a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.)

Comment: I too have been experiencing this issue. I would be curious as to finding out what the root cause is as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem - an SQLite query that ran fine pre-Lollipop was running a *lot* slower on Lollipop. It was a query on 3 joined tables, and was taking more than 10 seconds!

After trying all sorts of things, I found the problem: Lollipop uses SQLite 3.8, which uses a different Query Optimizer, and for some reason, it was using the wrong Index in one of the joins.

After getting a copy of the DB off my test device, I used the command line SQLite tool with "explain query plan" on the query. Comparing the output from pre-3.8 to post-3.8, the latter was using a different and incorrect Index.

From what I read, running "ANALYZE" over the DB may have fixed it, but since I didn't really need the wrong index it was using, I just dropped the index. Now the query uses the right index, and the query is fast again.